# NavigationView inside TabView: How to get to top-level TabView when using the TabItem-Buttons

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, tabview

I have got my `ContentView`, which is a `TabView`, with `View1` and `View2` as tabs:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Tab = .View1

    enum Tab {
        case View1
        case View2
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            View1()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View1", systemImage: "")
                }
                .tag(Tab.View1)
                        
            View2()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View2", systemImage: "")
                }
                .tag(Tab.View2)
        }
    }
}
```

`View1` is a `NavigationView` with a `NavigationLink` to a Subview:

```
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Subview1")) {
                Text("Hello, View1!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm in the SubView in `View1`, change via the tabs to `View2` and change back (again, via tab) to `View1`, it restores the Subview, which is fine. How can I achieve that by pressing the tab for `View1` *again*, it gets me to the top-level of `View1` (i. e. `View1` with "Hello, View1"). As of now I have to use the `NavigationLink` in the top left corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible approach is to use proxy binding with side effect to reset view having navigation view, so git it to initial state.

Demo prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Tab = .View1

    // force-reset property
    @State private var reset = UUID()       
    
    enum Tab {
        case View1
        case View2
    }

    var body: some View {

        let proxy = Binding(get: {selection}, set: {
            if selection == $0 {
                reset = UUID()     // << update if same tab clicked !!
            }
            selection = $0
        })

        TabView(selection: proxy) {
            View1()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View1", systemImage: "")
                }
                .tag(Tab.View1)
                .id(reset)        // reset on changed !!
            
            View2()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View2", systemImage: "")
                }
                .tag(Tab.View2)
        }
    }
}
```